# AutoCompleteTextView don't show dropdown when I come back to this activity after go to another activity

Tags: android, android-activity, autocompletetextview

I use a adapter to fill the AutoCompleteTextView. At first,everything goes fine.The AutoCompleteTextView works fine.Then I want to go to another activity to do some work.But when I come back,the AutoCompleteTextView do not show any dropdown even if the adapter has its right data.
How can I fix it?

```
  ArrayAdapter adapterStart;
  AutoCompleteTextview busInfo_start;
  AutoCompleteTextview busInfo_start;
  List<AutoCotent> auto_list;// Before the code below,these variable have already initialized
  adapterStart = new AutoTipAdapter(view.getContext(),R.layout.auto_tip_item, auto_list);

  busInfo_start.clearListSelection();
  busInfo_start.clearComposingText();
  busInfo_start.setFocusable(true);
  busInfo_start.setAdapter(adapterStart);
  adapterStart.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Did you try calling `busInfo_start.showDropDown()` to force the dropdown to display?

Comment: @MH. I tried,but the DropDown only show on the screen for about 0.1 second,then disappeared.So I also can't choose the autocompletetextview

Comment: @MH.  After set some attributes,the dropdown displays,but it can't filter the text in the adapter.It shows the whole items of the adapter.